# Applied statistical propensity score matching with panel data. (Economics)

Tags: econometrics, causality, propensity-scores, matching

Im am working on a university project that tries to estimate the kausal impact of childbirth and and labour income. The problem can be described as follows. In theory you would need childbirth to be assigned randomly. In practice individuals self select themselves into the treatment group (having children). I want to use propensity score matching to surpass that problem. The period of observation varies heavily across all individuals (some are observed from 1980-1985, some are observed from 1990-2020). Most of the variables that I want to match on are time invariant (year of birth, country of origin, school leaving degree, gender, ...) but one important variable (age) varies over time.

For individuals observed to have children within time of observation it is easy to determine labour income indexed by the time before and after having children. For the potential matches the event of having children did not occur. Therefore I can only determine the hypothetical year of having a child for an individual of the control group after the matching process. The following problem arises: Lets say 2 individuals are matched that are observed within completely different periods of time or the individual from the treatment group has had the child at a time where the individual from the control group has not been observed. In this case the match would be useless.

Hence I need individuals that are matched to be observed in time periods that are as close as possible. I wonder how I can incorporate that condition in the matching process and in my regression equation. I had the following idea. Using a location parameter like mean, median or quantile this information as time invariant variable in the regression equation.

I am looking for other ways to solve that problem. Any idea is highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at the `PanelMatch` package?